# How can I use keyboard navigation on TypingClub.com?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

Whenever I complete a typing lesson on [TypingClub.com](https://www.typingclub.com/), I'm forced to use my mouse to navigate to the next lesson. However, it feels a bit counter-intuitive to require a mouse for lessons on touch-typing.

[According to the documentation](https://s.typingclub.com/view_update/keyboard-navigation.html), TypingClub School Edition includes shortcuts for keyboard navigation, but these shortcuts don't work for TypingClub.com's online lessons.

**How can I use keyboard navigation to advance between lessons on TypingClub.com?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an exclusive feature for the School Edition version of TypingClub, however, according to support (see below), this option will become available to all users in the near future;

> Thank you for reaching out to us. This is an exclusive feature that is
>   available using our School Edition version of the software, however,
>   this option will become available to all users within the next week or
>   so.
>
> Regards,
>
> Ashli Hough
>   Customer Engagement Specialist, TypingClub

Comment: What is your source for this information?

Comment: As mentioned, from a discussion with TypingClub. I suggest contacting support for details on their schedule.